# Unity Csharp - Trouble saving user input for later use?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-input

I am having trouble figuring out how to gather user input and then save it for later use. I couldn't find a similar question on stack overflow, and I've asked other programmers for help, but to no avail.

Hopefully someone on here knows. In one scene, you get to type in whatever input you choose and it displays what you've written. Here is my code:

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;
    using UnityEngine.UI;
    public class TextInput : MonoBehaviour {
InputField input;
InputField.SubmitEvent se;
public Text output;
//public static string[] tasks = new string[]


//variable of array of strings so that you can save output text
void Start () {

    input = gameObject.GetComponent<InputField>();
    se = new InputField.SubmitEvent();
    se.AddListener(SubmitInput);

    input.onEndEdit = se;

}


public void SubmitInput(string arg0)
{


    string currentText = output.text;
    string newText = currentText + arg0 + " has been added to your schedule." + "\n";
    output.text = newText;
    input.text = "";

    // save currentTezt for later use outline
    //tasks.add(currentText)  

    /*Want to make each new text input equal a different amount of time
     */



}

//Need public array so that you can choose from the different strings --- you need the 'append' so that you can continue adding new tasks
```

}

How would I carry over the input so that I can use it and display it in the next scene. I apologize if the answer is really simple, I am still learning and I hope to get better. Thank you yet again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using `DontDestroyOnLoad`? documentation for it is found [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html).

There is a question on the unity forums similar to your question [here](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/how-to-pass-information-from-one-scene-to-another.23344/).

Answer (score 0):

The solution recommended by Unity (*):

1. Create a GameObject, preferably in the root, and give it a name e.g. "Persistent Data"
2. Put [DontDestroyOnLoad] immediately above the "class" part at top of the file, which tells Unity to keep it around in all scenes
3. Create a Component to store your data. Generally, create a different one for each set of data you want to save - e.g. "DataFromPlayerCreation", "DataFromWinningTheGame"
4. Add as many fields to each as you need, e.g. DataFromPlayerCreation.UserInput (you didn't descrive what your input is, so I've no idea if it's a name, a password, whatever)
5. Attach those Component's to 1 above
6. Use Application.LoadLevel as normal - your object from 1. above is the only thing that WON'T be destroyed, and will be dragged into the next scene

(*) - NB: this is a pretty crappy way of doing it, but it's the only one supported by Unity out-of-the-box. That's why it's the official one.